# How to delete project nature in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to delete the project nature which i added before using the extension point(org.eclipse.core.resources.nature).

Please help me with sample code.

Comment: It isn't clear what your are asking here. What did you do originally? What have you defined with the extension point?

Comment: By using the above mentioned extension point i have created my customised nature and adding it my project. Now i want to delete that nature which i have added before.

Comment: Please let me know if still you are not clear with the problem. I want to delete my customised nature in .project file.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a nature id from a project using something like:

```java
void removeNatureId(IProject project, String removeId) throws CoreException
{
  IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();

  String [] natureIds = description.getNatureIds();

  for (int i = 0; i < natureIds.length; ++i) {
    if (natureIds[i].equals(removeId)) {
      String [] newIds = new String [natureIds.length - 1];

      System.arraycopy(natureIds, 0, newIds, 0, i);
      System.arraycopy(natureIds, i + 1, newIds, i, natureIds.length - i - 1);

      description.setNatureIds(newIds);

      project.setDescription(description, null);

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to delay running this you could perhaps using a `WorkspaceJob`:

```java
class RemoveJob extends WorkspaceJob
{
  RemoveJob()
  {
    super("Remove Job");

    setSystem(true);

    // Use scheduling rule to make sure the job doesn't run until workspace is unlocked
    setRule(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
  }

  @Override
  public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
  {
    // TODO do the remove

    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
}
```

Create and schedule with:

```java
Job job = new RemoveJob();

job.schedule();
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned way, but the problem is here i am trying to delete my nature while using the IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_Delete operation. So, After setting the project description i am getting an exception like org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: The resource tree is locked for modifications.

Comment: So, now i am looking for alternative way to delete the nature or please help me how to resolve that exception.

Comment: Well you will have to arrange to run the code later on when the resource tree is unlocked. Possibly use a `WorkspaceJob`. If the resource tree is locked there is no way you can do this during the event.

Comment: If possible can you provide me sample code about to deal this issue.

Comment: Added example workspace job - I have not tested this for you use case.

Comment: I have tried with the above mentioned code, but i am getting project not found/ exists exception. I am calling above mentioned job in IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_Delete block. still i am getting project not found/exists exception

Comment: I am getting an exception like org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/myProject' does not exist.

Comment: Well then the project doesn't exist. If the PRE_Delete event is for a project which is being deleted you can't do anything more on that project. In future when asking a question you need to provide all those sort of detail in the question.